# Send mail with nodemailer in NodeJS with Angular5 front-end

Tags: node.js, email, angular5, nodemailer

I want to send an email from my nodejs server whenever i register a user. I'm using Angular5 as front-end. It doesn't return any error, but it doesn't work either. It's like my function is not being called at all. This is what I tried(email not real in this example):

**server.js**

```
app.post('/sendMails', function(req,res) {

    console.log("WENT INTO SEND MAILS!!!")


    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        port: 25,
        auth: {
            user: 'someemail@gmail.com',
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
        },

        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },

    });

    let HelperOptions = {

        from: '"Babababa" <someemail@gmail.com>',
        to: 'someemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Hello world',
        text: 'hey dude'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
           return console.log(error);
           res.json({error: "API Error"});
        }

        else{
            console.log("The message is sent: " + response.message);
            res.json({response: "sent"})
        }




    })


    });
```

from Angular

**UserService.ts (relevant parts)**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

      sendMail(user: User){
    console.log("sendMail()  was called.")
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/sendMails", user.email);
  }
```

This is called in my registration component on signup

**registration.component.ts**

```
     public signUp(){

    //marks all fields as touched.
    this.fs.markFormGroupTouched(this.registerForm);


    if(this.registerForm.valid) {

      let user: User = this.registerForm.value;
      console.log(user)

      this.userService.createUser(user);
      this.userService.sendMail(user); //<--- only this is relevant for this case.

    }
    else {
      //shows the error messages, for the not valid input fields.
      this.formErrors = this.fs.validateForm(this.registerForm,
      this.formErrors, false)
    }



  }
```

When i run this code there's no errors. In the inspector/ client-side console window i see the message **"sendMail()  was called."**, which means it's definetly calling my service. However, I recieve no mail nor any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http.post()` inside `sendMail()` returns an observable. You **must subscribe to this observable**, otherwise it will **not** be executed.

So in `registration.component.ts` you need something like:

```
this.userService.sendMail(user).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have a return statements in your sendMail function call. In the error block, the res.send is unreachable code. The edit code below:

```js
app.post('/sendMails', function(req,res) {

    console.log("WENT INTO SEND MAILS!!!")


    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        secure: false,
        port: 25,
        auth: {
            user: 'someemail@gmail.com',
            pass: process.env.MAIL_PASSWORD
        },

        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        },

    });

    let HelperOptions = {

        from: '"Babababa" <someemail@gmail.com>',
        to: 'someemail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Hello world',
        text: 'hey dude'
    };

    transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions, (error, response) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
           return res.json({error: "API Error"}); // return should be here instead of at console.log
        }

        else{
            console.log("The message is sent: " + response.message);
            return res.json({response: "sent"})
        }




    })


    });
```